# uibModal with a different URL document

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having the toughest time figuring out how to get my modal to work.
I have a main application document.
I have my modal code to open a modal with a different document.
When I run the document link by itself it works, but when I try to open it in the modal it doesn't seem to find its controller

> angular.js:12314Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ng/areq?p0=SimpleCtrl&p1=not[object Object]%function%C%got%undefined

```
 $scope.openPopup2 = function (size, qCode) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: ('core/media/media.nl?id=11457&c=TSTDRV1365574&h=a2ecbb8c50da60473910&_xt=.html?qcode='
            +qCode
            +'&productid='
            +$scope.siteInformation.productId),
            scope: $scope,
      controller: SimpleCtrl,
      size: size,
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

I have tried to remove "controller: SimpleCtrl,"
and even put it in quotes controller: "SimpleCtrl"

I just get similar errors.

The SimpleCtrl gets referenced from the new document that is supposed to appear.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you define SimpleCtrl? It must be defined in your main application JavaScript...

Comment: I agree with @Michael Rose's comment.  Additionally, when you get that figured out, the controller name is a string and should be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, like @Michael Rose's comment I moved it to the main application. I was hoping to just have the page load it itself. I stopped fighting it and put it into the main app and it works now. thanks